# Last Week Job Schedule

Tags: scheduled-tasks, sql, ms-sql

I'm looking for a way to scheduled MSSQL jobs to run only on the last week of the month?

I see the current options are daily,weekly or month, 
[image]

[image]

When selecting monthly, you can select the day number, or a predefinated day

[image]

[image]

Anybody know how

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you saying you want it to run each weekday in the last week of each month?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, that is correct.

Comment: Well that's hard to discern, as the last Monday of the month may be AFTER the last Tuesday, Wed, Thurs, Fri. of that month.  You'll need to better define the rules, what's acceptable, what's not etc.